ros2 jazzy rviz camera no image problem
i can launch my robot with demo_launch.py in gz sim and rviz but when i try to get camera images, it says no image. i added the camera sensor in urdf file and i can see the /image_raw topic in ros2 topic list. i am using ros2 jazzy in ubuntu 24.04 and gz sim 8.6.0. what should i do? my urdf file is:`
























































































































































































  
    
      
        
      
      
      
        
      
    
  
  
  
    
    
    
  
  
  
    
      30.0
      
        1.047
        
          640
          480
          R8G8B8
        
        
          0.1
          100.0
        
      
      
        true
        30.0
        camera_sensor
        image_raw
        camera_info
        camera_link
      
    
  
`

I am sorry, more information is needed to answer this question. Could you share your camera setup SDF, your gz_ros_bridge.yaml
